# What is the Gunsmith reputation for?

Tags: destiny

Before *The Taken King*, the following factions allowed you to gain reputation to purchase new weapons and equipment:

**Vanguard, Crucible, Dead Orbit, Future War Cult, New Monarchy, Crota's Bane, Queen's Wrath, House of Judgement, and Iron Banner**

After *The Taken King* was released, the lonesome vendor that nobody ever visits, the *Gunsmith*, now has reputation. However he does not possess any items that are purchasable through increasing your rank.

Does anybody know what the reputation for the *Gunsmith* will be used for?

My only speculation is that it would be similar to the *Cryptarch* where you obtain additional items for each rank after rank 3.

Comment: I am really enjoying the rank 2 sniper rifle that hunter gets from the gunsmith. It is definitely worth it to rank this reputation.

Comment: @TravisJ I sadly haven't even reached rank 1 yet. Is there an easy button to rank up quickly?

Comment: I would suggest just doing the test "bounties" for the guns he sells. You can do a whole set only once a week so do it today before the reset and then you can do it tomorrow and you should be rank 1 at least. If you can do that, then you can purchase the first order which arrives wednesday (in two days) and get a legendary from him :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gunsmith has his only weekly event called Armsday which allows players to order from a selection of 6 legendary weapons of random type and manufacturer. The ordered weapon is delivered to you via the Gunsmith the following Wednesday (Armsday), the weapons perks are randomized and are not the same for every player. At this time his weekly field-test weapons and weapons available for ordering will also change.

Players can start ordering weapons when their reputation with the Gunsmith is at least rank 1. You can place 1 order at rank 1 with the gunsmith and as you raise your rank you are able to place additional orders per week.

He also gives quests at ranks 2 and 3 that gives class-specific rewards. Rank 2 rewards a legendary special weapon, and rank 3 rewards an exotic primary.

Comment: That is pretty neat. I have not hit rank 1 yet, so I would not have figured that out.

Comment: How do you raise rep with the gunsmith?

Comment: @GnomeSlice He has 5 field test weapons per week.  Each has an associated challenge, usually something like headshots, killing a specific enemy, or crucible kills.  Completing these tasks will charge the weapon up to 100% (you can see progress if you hover over the weapon).  Upon completion, you get about 200 rep (iirc), and then you can delete the weapon from your inventory.  You can also get some RNG drops to turn in for 200 rep each.

Comment: It's also worth noting that like other factions he will give you reward packages as you rank up which have the chance to include legendary weapons

Comment: Depending on your rank, when the ordered weapon is delivered, you get that many (your rank) variations of the weapon. You can only choose one, but it gives more perk variations, so you have greater chance of picking up something you actually like. I suspect this will have an upper limit. I am rank 3 and I get 3 choices per delivery.

Comment: The weapon perks *are not* randomized. Myself and 4 others obtained the same pulse rifle with the same perks yesterday.

Comment: In addition, with higher rep levels you get more perk choices when picking up your guns. I was rank 2 last Armsday, and reached rank 3 later in the week. I checked the weapons prior to increasing rank, and I had 2 choices. After ranking up I had 3 choices.

Comment: The rank per gun order is not accurate. At level 2, I have placed 3 orders. It does not tell me I cannot place more, like it did at level 1 after the first order.

Comment: @Timelord64  Note: I didn't say that in my original answer. I simply said raising your rank allows for more orders. VanBuzzKill edited my post to add the additional (incorrect) info. I will re-edit it now.

Comment: My apologise. @VanBuzzKill should be aware by now that key alterations like that are bad form, unless you have personally written the question. They should have posted it as a comment, and left it up to you to determine accuracy. For future reference, you are free to roll back these kind of posts immediately, or at a later date, as the OP.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Or it is you who are incorrect and should not dictate alterations with false information.

Answer (score 1):

As Justin notes, there are three ranks, and at each one there are rewards.

- 1) Place **one** order for a weapon each week. There is a set of these you will see if you are rank 1 or above for sale just beneath the testing set he sells.
- 2) Place **two** orders for a weapon. The item purchased is 2500 glimmer and remains in your inventory until redeemed each week. In addition, receive a bounty which awards a legendary class weapon.
- 3) Place **three** orders for a weapon each week. In addition, receive a bounty which awards an exotic class weapon.

When purchasing a item to redeem, the item must be held until wednesday at which point it may be obtained by trading the placeholder item in. The weapon redeemed will have the same roll on it that week for everyone, but each week the roll will differ.

Obtaining reputation with the gunsmith goes very quickly. It is fairly straightforward. The gunsmith sells weapons which are common (200 attack rating) and in each weapons description there is a checkbox which details a way of "charging" the weapon. Completely this to 100% will yield reputation with the gunsmith, it does not need to be turned in, and can be dismantled upon completion. It is 250 reputation awarded per completed weapon test. The weapons available for testing reset once per week on wednesday.

Comment: Placing orders should not be confused with testing weapons.

Comment: In that case you are just flat out wrong. There is nothing you cite as evidence here. I have two characters one at rank 5 and one at rank 3 at the moment and have seen this twice already. You can read online here: https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3mgyoz/dont_forget_to_get_your_gunsmith_arms_day_orders/ at a reddit and see them all repeatedly reference two packages at rank two. In short, you are terribly mistaken. Here is another source citing the two orders are rank 2: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/716732-destiny/72504997

Comment: Do you perhaps mean you canonly pick between a set amount of options per weapon, as opposed to ebtire weapons, themselves? This would make much more sense..